# find with regex. Using string literals from variable

Tags: regex, bash, find

I know that shell doesn't really have arrays, but I know that I can do this with a list of values:

```
dir_array=("quarantine" "720" "low" "high" "DVD" "error" "keep")

for d in "${dir_array[@]}"
do
…
done
```

I also know that I can exclude these directories from find using -regex and -prune:

```
find -E . \
-type d -regex './(DVD|quarantine|720|high|low|error|keep)' -prune -o \
-type f -iregex '.*.(avi|wmv|mp4|m4v|mov|mkv)' -print
```

So, finally, here's my question:

How can I use my original $dir_array in the (first) regex in the find instead of repeating myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could convert the array into a string variable and then use the variable in the find command, like this:

```
str=`echo "./(${dir_array[@]})" | sed "s/ /\|/g;"` 
echo "$str"
```

Comment: Perfect - and I even understand it!  Thank you for the fast response.